# Python zipfile works partially on Windows?

Tags: python, windows

I'm using `zipfile` in my script to unzip .zip files. Here's my code:

```
def unzip(src, dst):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(src)
    for member in zf.infolist():
        words = filter(None, member.filename.split('/'))
        path = dst
        for word in words[:-1]:
            drive, word = os.path.splitdrive(word)
            head, word = os.path.split(word)
            if word in (os.curdir, os.pardir): continue
            path = os.path.join(path, word)
        zf.extract(member, path)
    dirMacosx = "%s/__MACOSX" % (dst)
    if os.path.exists(dirMacosx):
        shutil.rmtree(dirMacosx)
```

When I unzip a file on Linux or OS X, it works fine, but when I run it on Windows, it created a directory and all the directories in it, but none of the files. Why might this be?

Comment: At a glance, the path separator in windows is \

Comment: Try changing `words = filter(None, member.filename.split('/'))` to `words = filter(None, member.filename.split(os.sep))`

Comment: @Cthulhu but it can work with `/`, right? I thought it understood both, I've been using `/` for everything on WIndows and it works fine.

Comment: @tkbx: I don't know whether it does in some cases (that is, whether `os` converts it), but it certainly won't in `member.filename.split('/')`. In that case, `member.filename` is just a string- it has to be split using one character or the other.

Comment: You can use `os.path.sep` to get the correct separator character for the OS the script in running on.

Comment: @tkbx A filename containing a / in it is not permitted which is probably why windows didn't create the files.

Comment: `os.sep` worked perfectly, someone might want to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For compatibility with Unix-like and Windows, replace

```
words = filter(None, member.filename.split('/'))
```

with

```
words = filter(None, member.filename.split(os.sep))
```

This will use a `/` on Unix-like, and a `\` on Windows.